# Socket.IO emitting to specific room not working, it's sending to all sockets

Tags: socket.io

I'm using socket.to('XYZ')  to send to a room, but for some reason it's sending to sockets not in the room. Does anyone know why this would be happening? Here's a screenshot, as you can see I looked for sockets in the room PPPC but its returning a socket that isn't in that room. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[image: Looking for sockets in room PPPC]

[image: Testing with a random room also returns all sockets]

Edit- Added more code:

Creating a namespace `/game` in my server file: [image: namespace]

Then I import that namespace in my Game class

Later on in one of my methods I call `this.socket.to('PPCC').emit(...)` and this message is emitted to all sockets rather than just the sockets in the room. I verified that the sockets receiving the message were not in the room it was sent to.

When I was debugging I found that `this.socket.to('PPCC').sockets` was returning sockets that weren't in the room 'PPCC'.

index.ts:

```js
export const g = io.of("/game");
g.on("connection", (client) => {
  const { id: room, uid, nick } = client.handshake.query;
  const game = Game.getGame(room);
  console.log(`Connection in lobby ${room} (${nick})`);
  if (!game) {
    console.log("404 game does not exist");
    return client.disconnect(true);
  }

  const player = game.getPlayer(uid);
  if (!player) {
    console.log("Player does not exist");
    return client.disconnect(true);
  }

  client.join(room);
  player.active();
  game.checkActive();
  g.to(room).emit("lobby", game.state.players);
  client.emit("game", game.serialize());

  if (player.state.drawing) {
    client.emit("drawing", game.state.currentWord);
  }
  
  game.emitMessage();
});
```

Game.ts

```js
import { g } from "..";

class Game {
   constructor() {
    this.socket = g; // imported from server file
    this.id = 'ABCD'
    }
   emitMessage() {
     this.socket.to(this.id).emit(...) // sent to all sockets
     // note- I ran this.socket.to(this.id).sockets and found that it contained sockets not in the room
   }
}
```

Comment: minimum, add some code.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I added some more code, thank you for the help!

Comment: sorry I'm using a very old PC and I cannot see images. You have to paste text.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial no worries! I added code to the bottom. I had to simplify it because my code is extremely long. My best guess right now is that maybe the emit is not working because I am importing the SocketIO namespace from my `index.ts` file and then assigning that to a variable before I emit. The emit only doesn't work from Game.ts in the function `emitMessage()`.

Comment: did u accidentally join 'ABCD'

Comment: No I double checked that the sockets were not in 'ABCD' :/

Comment: try console.log(socket.rooms) on connection